# COM Exception while inserting a multi dimensional list to an excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel, list, excel-interop

I trying to figure out a way to insert a `multi dimensional C# list` into an `excel sheet` using `interop assembly` I have several rows of data in my list spread over 8 columns. But when I executed my query it threw me a `COM Exception  from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC` and I have the following code

```
public void ExportStructureListToExcel(List<StructuresDS> listExport, string sheetName)
{
    try
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet1 = null;
        worksheet1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
        worksheet1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)workbook.ActiveSheet;

        for (int i = 1; i < listExport.Count + 1; i++)
        {
             for (int j = 1; j < 8; j++)
             {
                  worksheet1.Cells[i, j] = listExport[i - 1];
             }
        }

        string fileDestination = @"S:\Parser Project\sde.xls";
        if (File.Exists(fileDestination))
        {
             File.Delete(fileDestination);
        }

        workbook.SaveAs(fileDestination, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        workbook.Close(true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        Process.Start(fileDestination);
        app.Quit();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
}
```

**StructureDS structure**

```
  public class StructuresDS
        {
            public DateTime time;
            public string CC;
            public string term;
            public string strike;
            public string strategy;
            public double? premium;
            public int volume;
            public double ratio;
            public string over;
        }

**Inserting elements to the List**



 listStructures.Add(new StructuresDS
               {
                   time = Convert.ToDateTime(AxiomSubSet[0].time.ToString("HH:mm:ss")),
                   CC = AxiomSubSet[0].CC,
                   term = listCodedTerms[0],
                   strike = (Convert.ToDouble(AxiomSubSet[0].strike) * 100).ToString(),
                   strategy = AxiomSubSet[0].strategy,
                   premium = Convert.ToDouble(AxiomSubSet[0].price),
                   volume = Convert.ToInt32(AxiomSubSet[0].quantity)
               });
```

The error is being thrown at  `worksheet1.Cells[i, j] = listExport[i - 1];`
I am not able to find a solution to this. May I know where I am wrong?

Comment: You haven't said which line is throwing the error.

Comment: it is at  worksheet1.Cells[i, j] = listExport[i - 1], I have edited the question

Comment: I think you need `worksheet1.Cells[i, j].Value = listExport[i - 1];`  Also, I don't know what StructureDS is, but you may need a property of that, rather than the structure itself.

Comment: Please check if you're not exceeding the size of your sheet. What version of excel are you using? What is the size of `listExport`?

Comment: @user845279. size of listExport is around 80 rows

Comment: I've tried your code and it works ok for me. I'm running Office 2007 and VS 2012.

Comment: @user845279 I am running Office 2013 and VS2012.

Comment: @Dev what is `List<StructuresDS>`? What is `StructuresDS`? What does it returns etc? Can you show the code for it

Comment: @mehow It is just a structure and I have added it in the edited question. Please  check

Comment: @Dev I think David's answer should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to set a cell to the structure.  You need to set it to one of the fields of the structure.  Something like:

```
worksheet1.Cells[i, j].Value = listExport[i - 1].over;
```

That (*.over*) may be the wrong field beause I don't know which one you actually want to put in the cell.